# git status get the "merging/rebasing/cherry-picking" part

Tags: git

`git status` correctly informs me of undergoing merges/rebases/cherry-picks, e.g. :

```
$ git status
On branch develop
You are currently cherry-picking commit 30ae0d6be.
  (fix conflicts and run "git cherry-pick --continue")
  (use "git cherry-pick --abort" to cancel the cherry-pick operation)
...
```

To view the state of my working directory, however, I use an alias to `git status --short --branch`, which will show me the state of files and the state wrt its remote tracking branch (number of ahead/behind commits),
but will not display information about the current "merge/rebase/cherry-pick" status.

**Question**

Is there a git command (an additional flag to `git status`, or another command altogether) which would describe the current state of undergoing merge/rebase/cherry-picks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `echo $(__git_ps1)`. `__git_ps1` does not print the newline, so `echo` is used here.

`__git_ps1` is used to add something like `(master|MERGING)` to `$PS1`. It's commonly seen in git-bash-for-windows.

See [Git in Bash](https://git-scm.com/book/uz/v2/Appendix-A%3A-Git-in-Other-Environments-Git-in-Bash).

Comment: The implementation [just checks](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4c86140027f4a0d2caaa3ab4bd8bfc5ce3c11c8a/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh#L428) `git` internal files.